# Django - global dictionary

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a teacher/student model where every student has one (or zero) teacher and teachers have multiple students. The teacher should be able to see a list of students and the students don't need to see anything other than their own teacher.

The differences between the teacher and student are few for my uses. So, I made just one custom model User and when registering you can choose whether you are a student or administrator. If you are an administrator, you must enter a "class code" for which students can sign up under your name.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    "username, password, email, etc.. goes here" 

    usertype = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=True)
    classcode = models.CharField(max_length=140, null = True, unique=True)
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(
                settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                null = True
                )
    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

For teachers the teacher field would be null and for students, obviously, there would be a link to the teacher.

I'm trying to manage the signup right now.

```
def create_user(self, email, username, password, first_name, last_name):
    user = self.model(
         email = self.normalize_email(email),
         username = username, first_name = first_name, last_name = last_name)
    if user.usertype == "admin":  # user is a teacher 
        user.is_staff = True 

        ### put code here ###

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user
```

I was thinking that when a teacher signs up, I would have a dictionary from {classCode: teacher's username (or teacher object themself(?))}. I realized that making a global variable to do this is difficult. Is there a different, easier way I might approach this without using a dictionary?

Comment: I don't understand why you need a dictionary at all, let alone a global one. What would it be doing? Storing data is what the database is for.

Comment: @DanielRoseman If the students sign up using a class code, how would I connect the class code to the already-registered teacher without something like a dictionary?

Comment: By getting it from the database: `User.objects.get(classcode=whatever, is_staff=True)`.